# ubuntu 16.04 update error after installing mysql

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, mysql

After installing `mysql` on `Ubuntu 16.04`, during software updating following error show:

```
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-apt-config_binary-amd64_Packages (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-apt-config_binary-i386_Packages (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-apt-config_binary-all_Packages (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-apt-config_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-apt-config_i18n_Translation-en (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-tools_binary-amd64_Packages (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-tools_binary-i386_Packages (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-tools_binary-all_Packages (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-tools_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_utopic_mysql-tools_i18n_Translation-en (1)

W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

using `apt-get update` and removing `/var/lib/apt/lists` don't work.

What should I do?

Comment: did you try: `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`  `sudo apt-get clean` `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: How did you install `mysql`?

Comment: yes. I tried that. but next time I try to update the same story happened. I install that using recommended deb file for ubuntu  in mysql website.

Comment: please share the link you used in order to install MySQL

Comment: I think I used this: [link]https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/